# Why doesn't my squaring function run?

Tags: python, math, terminal

I decided to make a program that would square a number just for fun. Using an online compiler, I entered my code and from what I saw there were no errors; it wouldn't run it would just have a blank console entry.

My code:

```
import math

def square():
    number = raw_input("Please enter a number for me to square.")  
    number*number  
    print "Your answer is..."  
    print number
```

Repl.it output:

[image]

Comment: You have to **call** your function first. Then you will see that you have to assign your calculation to a variable (possibly `number`).

Comment: You don't need the `import math` (in addition to the answer Martijn provided)

Answer (score 4):

Do make sure you also *call* your function:

```
def square():
    # your function body here

square()
```

But in your function, you are ignoring the result of your calculation here:

```
number*number
```

Assign that result to something:

```
answer = number * number
print "Your answer is..."  
print answer
```

You don't have a number, however. `raw_input()` returns a *string*, so you want to convert that to a number first:

```
number = int(number)
```

This assumes that the user actually entered something that can be converted to an integer; digits only, plus perhaps some whitespace and a `+` or `-` at the start. If you wanted to handle user errors gracefully here, take a look at [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for more advanced options.

Comment: I did the things mentioned but when I get it running it asks for the number but after I input a number and press enter I get this error,   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in square
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: @Galakras: updated; `raw_input()` returns a string, not an integer number.